# How to run Azure CLI commands in Azure Automation Account Python Runbook or Powershell Runbook

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cli, azure-automation

Is these any way to run Azure CLI commands in Azure Automation Account Python Runbooks or powershell runbooks ! 
I have few Azure CLI commands which were working perfectly fine in local PowerShell. I need to run same Azure CLI commands in Azure Automation Account Python Runbooks or in PowerShell runbooks.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is any native way to run Azure Cli commands in Azure Automation Runbook. You can use Azure Container Instances to work around that, but most of the things CLI can do Azure Powershell\Python can do as well, so you can use a native way of doing that.

Comment: Yeah.. You are true.. But using Azure CLI meets our needs much better. Because currently, I am looking a way to run those Azure CLI commands in Logic Apps.

Comment: Can run Azure CLI commands in Azure Functions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/scripts/functions-cli-create-serverless